# jQuery WYSIWYG editor with server images insertion

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

Can anyone advice a simple cross-browser rich text editor with the possibility to insert images from preloaded (uploaded on server) image list (as a pop-up with thumbs)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CKEditor ( http://ckeditor.com/ ) has some plugins like http://labs.corefive.com/Projects/FileManager/

or TinyMCE ( http://www.tinymce.com/tryit/full.php ) with MCFileManager or MCImageManager

Most common used :)

Comment: they are not so light-weight. I need just basic text editing functions.

Comment: @drunkcamel you can modify CKeditor, so you only have basic functionality.

Comment: CKEditor can easily be modified to be lightweight (remove lang, plugins etc) but else you can always use MC's plugins without TinyMCE... :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes TinyMCE is pretty Boss!! http://www.tinymce.com/